# Is there a way to know (persitents) client sessions on a mqtt server? - Mosquitto

Tags: session, mqtt, mosquitto

I need to know how many and which peristent session are active on a mqtt server.
I think it's out of standard and different mqtt servers have different implementation.
I'm using mosquitto version 2.0.17
Clients are using v5 protocol and cleanSession = false

I try subscribing at $SYS
but it only show me the number/state of connections, not the session name
[image: mosquitto with mqtt explorer]

Comment: This is not info Mosquitto provides via `$SYS` (and is [unlikely to provide in the future](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/655#issuecomment-353686793)). The MQTT spec does not dictate what info `$SYS` provides (just mentions that the topic may exist). In the above "disconnected" is persistent clients that are currently disconnected. I'm not sure how "connected persistent client" would be defined as, with MQTT v5, the "Session Expiry Interval" can be set in the DISCONNECT packet. [This issue](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2048#issue-793203152) may provide some options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution is to check the log files, stored fisically on mosquitto server.

Probably using some shell command you can periodically loop on that file(s) and do a publish on a retained topic with the name of the connected client.

I think this link can help
[mosquitto-logging](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-logging/)